# Modifying single structure member

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

How to edit a single member of a struct? For example I want to change `entity.name` from **foo** to **foobar**.

Part of the code:

```
void editing1(int cnt, int qq)
{
    Entity z;
    char tempc[255];
    int tempi = 0;
    cout << "Type in new name: ";
    cin >> tempc;
    qq--;
    Entity* ss = new Entity[cnt];
    while (fread(&z, sizeof z, 1, file)) {
        ss[tempi] = z;
        if (tempi == qq) {
            (*ss[tempi].name = *tempc);
        };
        tempi++;
    };

    purge();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < cnt; ii++) {
        fwrite(&ss[ii], sizeof(Entity), 1, file);
    };
    fclose(file);
    system("cls");
};
```

But I get this:

[image: snifty letters]

And it well ... corrupts the entire file. Original:

[image: good little symbols]

Also could someone explain why it corrupts the whole file instead the part where it is used?

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. As your code appears to be C-like I've removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @JBentley -- However, it also contains `cout` and `cin` which are decidedly not straight `C` -- that said, there's little point in restoring the `C++` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here is suspicious...

`(*ss[tempi].name=*tempc);`

Note that `ss` is a pointer to an array of `cnt` `Element` -- so, if you want to access the `tempi` element, the correct way to do that is not `(*ss[tempi])` but `ss[tempi]` -- if you are trying to access the first element of the `name` attribute then `*ss[tempi].name` would do that.

However, `tempc` is an array of char and without an array index, is the address of the first element in the array. `*tempc` would be the single character in the first byte.

The issue is that I don't know what `ss[tempi].name` is in order to tell you the correct way to assign it. This would be my solution **if** `name` is a char pointer.

`ss[tempi].name=tempc;`

if `name` is a char array, you would likely want something like this...

`strncpy( ss[tempi].name, tempc, sizeof( ss[tempi].name ) );`

`*ss[tempi].name` is the first character in `name` -- as you have stated, the attribute is `char name[255]` -- therefore, `name` by itself is the address of the first character in that array and `*name` is the actual first character. The same is true of `*tempc` -- so, you are copying the first byte from `tempc` to `name` and that's all.

Further, you cannot copy arrays by assigning them...

```
char array1[255] = "hello world";
char array2[255];

array2 = array1;
```

That is **NOT** legal `C`. You need to use a string copy to do that and you also need to protect against a buffer overrun, so you would do this...

```
char array1[255] = "hello world";
char array2[255];

strncpy( array2, array1, sizeof( array2 ) );
```

Comment: ss[tempi].name is an also array of 255 char. 

strncpy( ss[tempi].name, tempc, sizeof( (*ss)[tempi].name ) ); - also does not help me as it doesnt let me use the (*ss)[tempi].name ) part, however after removing () is also corrupting entire file.

Comment: Yeah... that's my mistake -- it should have been `sizeof( ss[tempi].name )` -- edited accordingly.

Comment: The funny thing is, I did not even edit the code. So thus please dont make so inadequately fast decisions

Comment: Okay... aside from that, the edits in my post hold. `(*ss[tempi].name = *tempc);` should be `strncpy( ss[tempi].name, tempc, sizeof( ss[tempi].name ) );`

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful after all but here is the right choice for me: cin>>tempe.name;strncpy(ss[id].name, tempe.name, sizeof(z.name));}

Answer (score 0):

```
*ss[tempi].name
```

should be

```
ss[tempi].name
```